# My Ubuntu terminal takes a long time to load!

Tags: gnome-terminal, 18.10

I am using Ubuntu 18.10. When I open my terminal it takes approximately 10 seconds to load completely. Here is the [video link](https://streamable.com/gpisn) to my problem.

Comment: Hey Faisal, have you added anything to your `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, or `~/.profile` that could be slowing down the loading process?

Comment: Do `bash -x ~/.bashrc` and see which command takes the most time.

Comment: Your _terminal_ loads almost instantly, your _shell_ does not.

Comment: yeah! my terminal is delaying to get the prompt in the terminal. @egmont

Comment: @CarrotIsland i didnt edit anything. My terminal is delaying to get the prompt in the terminal from the first of my ubuntu installation.

Comment: I sometimes have the same problem. But `bash -x ~/.bashrc` doesn't even take a second. Edit: I found this, maybe it helps: https://serverfault.com/questions/722494/why-does-it-take-tens-of-seconds-to-get-a-shell-prompt/722496

Comment: I believe you have a lot of SWAP memory used and your performance is affected by this... can you check your SWAP usage? by "free", "top", and/or "htop"? if so... try to swapoff your swap file... and see if the problem is solved... "swapoff /swapfile" (but check if you have enough physical memory to include the data in /swapfile)

Comment: @OmidGhayour it was on Nov 10, 2018. There is no way I can check it now :p

Thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 2):

you are/were probably low on resources...

If for a period you go low on resources, the operating system manages to send some data to swapfile to free the RAM, while /swapfile keeps a lot of data it is very slow due to hardware limitations of HDD in compare to RAM...

If your system is back to a state that has enough space in RAM... try to move the data to RAM as soon as possible...

for this you can check your swappiness by:

```
cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
```

if it is high (my default was 60 and I believed it was high) reduce it to a better value (I chose 25). For example if you think 10 is a good value for you use the following command:

```
sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=10
```

the above command would reset on restart. Foe more details please refer to the official documents like: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq